# Function to create a Category for each Group (BuddyPress) on creation

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm looking to have a category created for each BuddyPress Group when it's made. So far I've found this code which would create a Category once the Group was created. I would use this code in the Theme Functions.

```
function example_insert_category() {
  wp_insert_term(
    'Example Category Name',
    'category',
    array(
      'description' => 'This is an example category.',
      'slug'    => 'example-category-slug'
    )
  );
}
add_action('groups_group_create_complete', 'example_insert_category');
```

Firstly am I on the right track. Secondly how would I set the Category Name and Category Slug using the newly created Group Name and Group Slug?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function example_insert_category($group_id) {
  $group = groups_get_group( array( 'group_id' => $group_id) );
  //var_dump( $group ); 
  wp_insert_term(
    $group->name,
    'category',
    array(
      'description' => $group->description,
      'slug'    => $group->slug
    )
  );
}
add_action('groups_group_create_complete', 'example_insert_category');
```

Comment: I've just noticed that this only works if the user goes through all of the Group Create steps. But if they just complete the first step the category is not created but the Group still is. Do you know how to make this run when the Group is added to the database?

Comment: See do_action( 'groups_create_group_step_save_' . bp_get_groups_current_create_step() );  in function groups_action_create_group()  in buddypress\bp-groups\bp-groups-actions.php